# Songbird + Podcasts not working?

Tags: podcasts, songbird

Using Songbird 1.2.0 but cannot figure out how to get Podcasts to work with it. From what I understand that is what they call subscriptions, which I have added but nothing downloads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podcasts don't work well at all in Songbird yet.  The feed has to end in .xml for it to even read, even then they don't seem to process correctly.

[Here's a thread talking about the bugs.](http://getsatisfaction.com/songbird/topics/podcast_subscription_not_working)